# How can I remove a record when it has a higher level on column with SQL oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-delete

For example: 
I have two situations

```
  card cardholder level
    1     1         1
    1     1         2
    1     1         3

  card cardholder level

    1     1         2
    1     1         3
```

On both situations I only want the first record.

I got something like this, but do not return the expected:

```
delete from table
    where card in (select card from (
    select cardholder, card, count(card), count(cardholder) from table
    group by cardholder, card
    having COUNT (card) > 1))
    and level = '3'
    ;
```

Comment: Don't you have a primary key in your table?

Comment: If you don't have a PK the only thing you can key off of is adding an `order by card, cardholder, level`, you'll also want to add a `LIMIT` of 1

Comment: @schlonzo I have a table ID as PK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a correlated `DELETE` comparing with the `MIN` level value for each card,cardholder combination. I have changed the column `level` to `lvl` as `level` is an Oracle keyword.

```
DELETE
FROM tab1 t
WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM (
            SELECT card
                ,cardholder
                ,MIN(lvl) AS lvl
            FROM tab1
            GROUP BY card
                ,cardholder
            ) s
        WHERE t.card = s.card
            AND t.cardholder = s.cardholder
            AND
         t.lvl > s.lvl
        );
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/14067/1)

It is not totally clear what do you mean by

> "I only want the first record" .

I have assumed it to be `MIN`.

If you have an `ID` PK column and your first record means the one with the least id, then you may use `KEEP..DENSE_RANK` along with `MIN(lvl)`

```
MIN(lvl) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY ID )
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. Your assumption is correct :)
I want the min.

Comment: @Wiz : you'r welcome..Please let me know if it helped u.

Comment: Yep. It helped!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to leave the record with smallest `'level'` value, you can use below query:

```
DELETE FROM table t WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 table t2 WHERE t2.level < t.level)
```

Comment: I can only remove if the pair card and cardholder has more than 1 level.

Comment: So try this please: DELETE FROM table t WHERE card > 1  and cardholder > 1

Comment: hm, that does not make any sense... I guess.